# Comparing two files' dates in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

```
set File1 = C:\filepath
set File2 =C:\filepath

FOR %i IN (%FILE1%) DO SET DATE1=%%~ti\

FOR %i IN (%FILE2%) DO SET DATE2=%%~ti

IF "%DATE1%" GTR "%DATE2%" ECHO Files have same age && GOTO END

FOR %i IN ('DIR /B /O:D "%FILE1%" "%FILE2%"') DO SET NEWEST=%%i

ECHO Newer file is "%NEWEST%"
```

Comment: `for /f` or `FOR %i IN ('DIR /B /O:D "%FILE1%" "%FILE2%"')` doesn't work in DOS. [Windows cmd and MS-DOS are different things](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@echo off
rem --compares the age of two files
rem --by Vasil "npocmaka" Arnaudov

call :isOlder     "C:\test.file1" "C:\test.file2"

goto :eof

:isOlder [%1 path to first file ; %2 path to second file]
    setlocal
        call :get_file_c_time  "%~1" time1
        call :get_file_c_time  "%~2" time2
    if "%time1%" LEQ "%time2%"  (
          echo YES
         ) else (
          echo NO
         )
goto :eof

:get_file_c_time [ %1 path to file; %2 variable to assign value  ]
        set file_path=%~1

        if not exist "%file_path%" echo file %1 does not exist&& exit /b 1

        if "%~2" equ "" echo need a secont parameter && exit /b 2

        setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

        for /f "skip=5 tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims=/:.гчЈз " %%T in ('dir /tc "%file_path%"') do (
         if "%%Y" EQU "PM" (
          set /a "hour=%%W+12"
         ) else (
                set hour=%%W
         )
         set ftime=%%V%%U%%T!hour!%%Y
         goto :endfor
        )
:endfor

endlocal & set "%~2=%ftime%"
goto :eof
```

It depends on TIME settings but in the most of the cases should work..
Another approach is with WMIC/WMI but I will need some time to create script

Comment: may i know this line what is :.гчЈз ?                                       for /f "skip=5 tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims=/:.гчЈз " %%T in ('dir /tc "%file_path%"') do (
         if "%%Y" EQU "PM" (

Comment: @user3764876 year/hour token that could appear for different east Europe languages (as Im from Bulgaria) and the date string will be splitted by them.

Comment: @user3764876 - what is the output of your TIME and DATE commands? Usually in US/ENG settings there are no additional strings for the date .If the script is working for you , you can leave it unchanged.

Comment: its nots displaying any thing.. can you provide me the PDF file on my mail i.e. imtiyaz.uddin1225@gmail.com Thanks in Advance.